# Detecting and/or converting binary endianness (PPE [CELL] to Intel)

Tags: binary-analysis

I am by no means a competent programmer in any sense of the word. I've only ever fiddled with .NET building very, very basic applications. If it's possible to be given step-by-step instructions, then please do.

That said, my issue right now is figuring out a way to convert a binary file compiled for the CELL architecture to Intel. These are *binary* files rather than *executables*. I've thoroughly searched the net looking for answers, however all of them seem to refer to PowerPC instead of PPE.

In a perfect world, the preferred solution would entail simply dragging/dropping the big-endian files onto a conversion executable. Since this is not a perfect world, I wont look forward to such a thing.

NOTE 1: The binary files in question are 64 bit, judging from the [specs on the CELL architecture](http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps3/CELL_BE).

NOTE 2: Fortunately, I have versions of these binaries in both big and little-endian. Using UltraCompare (albeit taking an ungodly amount of time to compare,) I can verify byte-swapping in the headers when comparing against it's little-endian counterparts.

"If you have both versions, then why do you need to convert them?"

There are some binaries not available in little-endian and those are the ones I need.

Comment: If these are not executables, what are they? Some sort of resource bundles? If so, you'd need to know the exact file format. Then, writing a script to convert endianness won't be an issue.

Comment: "I can verify byte-swapping in the headers" ... is it just the headers that have their bytes swapped, or the data as well?

Comment: @GuntramBlohm - As far as I know, and according to research being done by others on this, it seems to indeed be just the headers. I'm not well-versed in this subject, so I can't give you a definitive answer. However, I can give you [a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/uwko8Rc.png) showing what I mean.

Comment: Seems like some stuff is byte-swapped, for example the headers up to byte 0x18; after the 5-byte "None\0", byte-swapping continues. But there are also ranges of bytes that seem wildly different, for example 0x41-0x51. If these two files are indeed reprentations of the same object, it seems conversion between them is much harder that just a few endianness swaps.